# Python quit unexpectedly running parallel processes with scipy.linalg.inv()

Tags: python, numpy, crash, parallel-processing

I try to run some tasks with `multiprocessing`s `Pool` by Python. All seems to work as it should, but one line lets Python quit unexpectedly, it is the line, which computes the inverse of a matrix. (`scipy.linalg.inv()`)

Apples error log prints

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000108
```

I am pretty sure, that it has something to do with the inverse, and not with some unknown variables, because the quit happens as well, if I just compute:

```
la.inv(np.eye(n))
```

I think it could have something to do with the fact, that `la.inv()` uses multiple threads.

Note: If I run the code without parallelization, it works of course.
*AND* it also works, if I just comment the line above.

*BUT* if I run some test code, that minimalizes the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
from multiprocessing import Pool


class ParClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ParClass, self).__init__()

    def compute(self,x):
        self.x = la.inv(np.random.randn(1000,1000))
        return self


def runPar(x):
        method = ParClassifier()
        method.compute(x)
        return method.x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    result = pool.map(runPar, np.arange(1,100))
```

The error does not occur. So why does a line of code that affects the hole process of my original problem does not affect a test problem? This is quite strange, however did anyone ever came across this before?

EDIT:
`np.linalg.solve()` does not do any better

Comment: Can you confirm that you're running OSX and that your numpy is linked against the Accelerate framework (you can probably find out from the output of `np.show_config()`)?